# How to defragment etcd database in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, etcd

I am trying to resolve a recurring Prometheus alert I'm getting that states that my Kubernetes cluster `etcd` database is fragmented and should be defragmented. I have never used the `etcdctl` command before, which is apparently installed automatically in the container in which `etcd` is running.

I have found a [post](https://blog.alekc.org/posts/fixing-etcddatabasehighfragmentationratio-prometheus-alert/) that gives a very brief description of what to do, but it does not work for me. I have also been looking at documentation on the etcd.io [site](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/op-guide/maintenance/#defragmentation), but everything there seems to assume the user is in the pod, running the `etcdctl` command directly.

The command I have tried to use is:

```
kubectl exec $(kubectl get pods --selector=component=etcd -A -o name | head -n 1) -n kube-system -- etcdctl defrag --cluster --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/apiserver.key --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/apiserver.crt
```

I am not 100% sure if I'm specifying the correct file paths for the `--key` and `--cert` options. The first link just uses `server.key` and `server.crt`, which it complains don't exist for my set-up. I did find the files `apiserver.key` and `apiserver.crt`, but maybe those are not the files to use. If they are not, I don't know what **should** be used.

I'm running this from Git Bash. It errors out with a message that seems to make no sense. It's almost as though it's trying to use the local filesystem (which is a PC running Windows 11).

The error message:

```
Error: open C:/Program Files/Git/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/apiserver.crt: no such file or directory
command terminated with exit code 128
```

Are these directions correct? Does anyone know why I might be getting the strange error?

**UPADTE**:

As suggested by @Botje, I ran the following (note the extra slash at the start of each file path):

```
$ kubectl exec $(kubectl get pods --selector=component=etcd -A -o name | head -n 1) -n kube-system -- etcdctl defrag --cluster --cacert //etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --key //etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/apiserver.key --cert //etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/apiserver.crt
```

Unfortunately this did not work either:

```
Error: open //etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/apiserver.crt: no such file or directory
command terminated with exit code 128
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to login to that host where etcd pods is running (usually Mater node) and execute :

```
etcdctl defrag
```

OR

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379  --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key defrag
```

prerequisite it to install etcdctl (by installing etcd to that host)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the command on one of the Kubernetes nodes where the etcd pods are running.

> I'm running this from Git Bash. It errors out with a message that seems to make no sense. It's almost as though it's trying to use the local filesystem (which is a PC running Windows 11).

That's because this is exactly what you are doing, and your Windows 11 install doesn't have the certificate files.